# Color selected portion of an image in android

Tags: android, colors, transparent

I am a newbie and wanted to know 
how to apply transparent color in selected portion of the image? I have coded like this but I am not getting the transparent color. Not able to see the below image.

```
       Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
       p.setColor(SettingsActivity.myColor);  
       p.setStrokeWidth(20);  
       p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
       p.setAlpha(0xFF);
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance
Prathima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Color Picker Dialog](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have edited my question. If you know this kindly reply